# How can I check If I get empty file_get_html in PHP HTML Dom?

Tags: php, json

I am getting `JSON` data through visiting a link using PHP HTML DOM, but sometimes, I get an empty page so I want to know that how can I really check if page is empty so that I can skip it by using continue in for loop
I am checking it through :

```
if (empty($jsondata))
```

But I always get `TRUE` never gets false even if page is returned empty

Here is my code :

```
 <?php
    $prefix = $_POST['prefix'];
    $start_product = $_POST['start_product'];
    $end_product = $_POST['end_product'];

    set_time_limit(0);

    for ($i=$start_product; $i <= $end_product; $i++) {

        include('simple_html_dom.php');

        $prefix ="00";
        $i= "11";

        $jsondata = file_get_html('http://www.ewallpk.com/index.php?controller=search&q=A'.$prefix.$i.'&limit=10&timestamp=1445547668758&ajaxSearch=1&id_lang=1');

        if (!empty($jsondata)) {

            $data = json_decode($jsondata, true);

            $product = file_get_html($data[0]["product_link"]);

            $product_name= "";
            foreach($product->find('div[id=pb-left-column] h1') as $element) {
                $product_name.=$element->innertext . '<br>';
            }

            $product_name = explode("_", $product_name);
            $count = count($product_name);

            if ($count < 3) {
                $product_name=$product_name[0];
            } else {
                $product_name = "Error";
            }

            $product_description= "";
            foreach($product->find('div[id=short_description_content]') as $element) {
                $product_description.=$element->plaintext . '<br>';
            }

            $product_price= "";
            foreach($product->find('p[class=our_price_display] span') as $element) {
                $product_price.=$element->innertext . '<br>';
            }

            $image_link= "";
            foreach($product->find('img[id=bigpic]') as $element) {
                $image_link.=$element->src;
            }

            $content = file_get_contents($image_link);
            file_put_contents('item_images/A'.$prefix.$i.'.jpg', $content);

            echo "<strong>Product No : </strong> A".$prefix.$i."</br>";
            echo "<strong>Product Name : </strong>".$product_name."</br>";
            echo "<strong>Product Description : </strong>".$product_description;
            echo "<strong>Product Price : </strong>".$product_price."</br></br></br>";
        } else {
            continue;
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Why are you calling `file_get_html` on a JSON file? Use `file_get_contents`.

Comment: BTW, don't put the `include` line inside the loop. Or use `include_once`. Otherwise you'll get errors about redefining the functions.

Comment: @Barmar I checked with `file_get_contents` too still I am getting true even when my link returns with empty page..!

Comment: And yes about `include` I was just checking the issue that's why I put that in there..!

Comment: What does `var_dump($jsondata)` show?

Comment: My guess is it's returning some spaces or newlines even when there's no JSON data. Try trimming `$jsondata` before you check if it's empty.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks it's fixed now..I didn't properly checked the `file_get_contents`

Comment: Can you post that as answer? I will select that..!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably getting some whitespace in the empty response, so trim it off before testing. You also should be using `file_get_contents`, since the response is not HTML.

```
$jsondata = file_get_contents('http://www.ewallpk.com/index.php?controller=search&q=A'.$prefix.$i.'&limit=10&timestamp=1445547668758&ajaxSearch=1&id_lang=1');
$jsondata = trim($jsondata);
if (!empty($jsondata)) {
    ...
}
```